# Setting ASP.NET Core TagHelper Attribute Without Encoding

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I want to add the `integrity` attribute to a script tag in my tag helper. It contains a `+` sign which I don't want encoded.

```
<script integrity="sha384-Li9vy3DqF8tnTXuiaAJuML3ky+er10rcgNR/VqsVpcw+ThHmYcwiB1pbOxEbzJr7"></script>
```

This is my tag helper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "script")]
public class MyTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // Omitted...

        output.Attributes["integrity"] = "sha384-Li9vy3DqF8tnTXuiaAJuML3ky+er10rcgNR/VqsVpcw+ThHmYcwiB1pbOxEbzJr7";
    }
}
```

This is the output of the above code, where `+` has been replaced by `&#x2B;`:

```
<script integrity="sha384-Li9vy3DqF8tnTXuiaAJuML3ky&#x2B;er10rcgNR/VqsVpcw&#x2B;ThHmYcwiB1pbOxEbzJr7"></script>
```

How can I stop this encoding from taking place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The provided code didn't work for me, as the `ProcessAsync` method wasn't called. There were some things wrong with this (abstract class can't be instantiated, there is no `script` attribute etc.).

The solution is basically that you create the `TagHelperAttribute` class yourself, instead of simply assigning the `string` type.

```
@section Scripts {
    <script></script>
}
```

The tag helper

```
[HtmlTargetElement("script")]
public class MyTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public const string IntegrityAttributeName = "integrity";
    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // Omitted...

        output.Attributes[IntegrityAttributeName] = new TagHelperAttribute(IntegrityAttributeName, new HtmlString("sha384-Li9vy3DqF8tnTXuiaAJuML3ky+er10rcgNR/VqsVpcw+ThHmYcwiB1pbOxEbzJr7"));

        await Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

This correctly outputs

```
<script integrity="sha384-Li9vy3DqF8tnTXuiaAJuML3ky+er10rcgNR/VqsVpcw+ThHmYcwiB1pbOxEbzJr7"></script>
```

The reason for this is, that `TagHelperAttribute` has an operator overload `public static implicit operator TagHelperAttribute(string value)` for the implicit (`=`) operator, which will create the `TagHelperAttribute` and pass the string as it's `Value`.

In Razor, `string`s get escaped automatically. If you want to avoid the escaping, you have to use `HtmlString` instead.

Comment: That works fine with attributes but not with the tag content.

Comment: @LordofScripts: For tag content you have `output.Content.Append(string unencoded)` or `output.Content.AppendHtml(new HtmlString("mystring&somethingelse")`

Comment: thanks, just figured it out now and was going to post and update. Great!

Comment: Helped a lot. HtmlString works very well - with .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: Or just use `output.Attributes.SetAttribute(IntegrityAttributeName, new HtmlString(...))`.