# Render raw html from view component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

For very simple ViewComponents I'd like to bypass a view and just return an encoded HTML string.

Example:

```
<ul>
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
<ul>
```

My self-made implementation is like this:

```
public class RawHtmlResult : IViewComponentResult
{
    public RawHtmlResult(string EncodedHtml)
    {
        _encodedHtml = EncodedHtml;
    }
    public string _encodedHtml { get; set; }

    public void Execute(ViewComponentContext context)
    {
        context.Writer.Write(_encodedHtml);
    }

    public Task ExecuteAsync(ViewComponentContext context)
    {
        return context.Writer.WriteAsync(_encodedHtml);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(long id)
{
    var someArray = await _someService(id);
    var ulHelper = new TagBuilder("ul");
    var liHelper = new TagBuilder("li");

    foreach (var setName in someArray)
    {
        liHelper = new TagBuilder("li");
        liHelper.InnerHtml.Append(setName);
        ulHelper.InnerHtml.Append(liHelper);
    }
    var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    ulHelper.WriteTo(writer, new HtmlEncoder());

    return new RawHtmlResult(writer.ToString());
}
```

So far I have not found a suitable IViewComponentResult. Do I miss apoint?

Comment: A View *is* raw html, mixed with markup. A controller should *not* have to do anything with rendering. Otherwise you shouldn't use MVC at all - it's the wrong pattern. Perhaps you are trying to solve a *different* problem? Why would you want to create raw HTML like this inside an MVC framework?

Comment: Maybe he is developing a CMS and his articlebody is stored as HTML in the database? ;)

Comment: You may also look into `HtmlString`. Used it a bit different answer for tag-helper content being encoded. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35672341/455493 Not sure though on how to use it inside a controller

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You have been absolutely right about MVC usage and I agree. Still, sometimes you do not need to follow the path 100% and I can keep my codebase smaller not introducing another "partial view"... Returning `Content("foo", "text/html");` does not work because ViewComponent only support returning String, HtmlString or IViewComponentResult. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @kdaveid Not in this case. You can easily return an array of values and use a loop in the View. Or use a proper model and pass the array as one of its properties. The total number of lines is *less* than what you already typed

Answer (score 4):

The `Invoke()` method on the view component does not need to return `IViewComponentResult`, it can return `HtmlString` so you don't need a custom implementation of `IViewComponentResult`.

For example:

```
public HtmlString Invoke()
{
    return new HtmlString(@"<b>Hello World</b>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return Content("<ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li><ul>");
```

The method is [Controller.Content](http://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Mvc/Controller/#meth-Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller.Content). You can also use it to return content types other than HTML.

As mentioned it's not the preferred way to return HTML - typically the controller should return a model and the view should provide HTML. It might be preferable to use a partial view. But scenarios come up where we have to do things like this. (I just encountered one myself.)

Comment: You also need to specify the 2nd argument, content type: `Content(html,"text/html")`

Comment: The second argument is optional.

Comment: I was under the impression that if you omitted the content-type it would always return text/plain but I just checked and it returns the correct content-type. Maybe that's new since MVC3.

Comment: The question is about ASP.NET Core / MVC6. The provided link refers to old framework up to MVC5, so likely not valid as MVC6 is a complete rewrite w/o System.Web.* and IIS dependencies

Comment: It's still in there. Updating the link to point to ASP.NET Core docs.

Comment: This does not work: Returning `Content("foo", "text/html");` does not work because ViewComponent only support returning String, HtmlString or IViewComponentResult. ([see above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597861/render-raw-html-from-view-component-in-asp-net-5#comment60848664_36597861))

Answer (score 0):

#### For future visitors:

The easiest way to return [`HtmlContentViewComponentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewcomponents.htmlcontentviewcomponentresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0) from `Invoke()` method. [`HtmlContentViewComponentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewcomponents.htmlcontentviewcomponentresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0) is one of [3 classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iviewcomponentresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0#derived) which implements [`IViewComponentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iviewcomponentresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0#derived) interface.

Here is the example code:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(object arguments)
{
    return new HtmlContentViewComponentResult(
        new HtmlString("<ul><li>My HTML code</li></ul>"));
}
```

As you may see [`HtmlContentViewComponentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewcomponents.htmlcontentviewcomponentresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0) requires `IHtmlContent` as content to render on view, so best way is to use `HtmlString` class.

---

Still for more complex results it's better to return *View* instead of generating raw HTML programmatically.