# Taghelper problems with rendering output.precontent using Tagbuilder and stringbuilder

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have tried this two different ways.. not a great deal on this in the forum either.

I am trying to create a custom taghelper slowly building it up as I move forward. Its to produce a dynamic menu however I am not getting the right output from string builder.

I am trying to produce this for the precontent:

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

and this for the postcontent:

```
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I intended to add this as output.precontent and output.postcontent. I also decided to use a tagbuilder approach for each tag and to add them to a stringbuilder finally rendering it as the forementioned precontent. This is what I came up with.

```
        StringBuilder PreContentSb = new StringBuilder();

        StringBuilder PostContentSb = new StringBuilder();

        TagBuilder divTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        TagBuilder ul = new TagBuilder("ul");

        divTag.MergeAttribute("class", "navbar - collapse collapse");
        divTag.TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.SelfClosing;

        ul.MergeAttribute("class", "nav navbar - nav");
        ul.TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.SelfClosing;

        PreContentSb.Append(' ', 12);
        PreContentSb.Append(divTag.InnerHtml.ToString());
        PreContentSb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        PreContentSb.Append(' ', 16);
        PreContentSb.Append(ul.ToString());
        PreContentSb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

        output.PreContent.SetContent(PreContentSb.ToString());

        PostContentSb.Append(' ', 16);
        PostContentSb.Append("</ul>");
        PreContentSb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        PostContentSb.Append(' ', 12);
        PostContentSb.AppendLine("</div>");
        PreContentSb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

        output.PostContent.SetContent(PostContentSb.ToString());
```

The taghelper is only going in one place so I thought I would indent for that place to start with eg "PreContentSb.Append(' ', 12);"..

The problem I am getting is that when I look at page source I am getting, for these tags the following:

```
          Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.BufferedHtmlContent&#xD;&#xA;                Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder&#xD;&#xA;                &lt;/ul&gt;            &lt;/div&gt;&#xD;&#xA;
```

First of all its not rendering the tagbuilt tags at all and secondly instead of inverted commas and angle brackets its displaying the actual Character entity references..

How do I simply display the inverted commas, angle brackets?

Finally how do you render a tagbuilder element in a stringbuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `TagBuilder` doesn't have an override to `ToString()`. You have to use `WriteTo()` to write the content of it (in i.e. a TextWriter).
2. To prevent escaping, you have to return a `HtmlString`. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672341/455493) on how to return a sting that's not being encoded by the template engine. The example is about attributes but it should give you an idea on how to do it, i.e. `output.PostContent.SetContent(new HtmlString(PostContentSb.ToString()));`

Comment: Quick question - how do I use WriteTo() to add the contents of the TagBuilder to the stringbuilder? (will up vote this)

Comment: var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            divTag.WriteTo(writer, new HtmlEncoder());
            var s = writer.ToString();